# notify when mysql database changes in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am looking for library or events or sample code in node.js sever that run continously and watch on mysql table and send notifications to front end when changes occour in table. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at Socket.io library for real time programming. You can emit events on every post request to your server and it is really easy to use.

[Socket.io Library for Node.js](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io)